# Running cloud-init twice via Packer & Terraform on VMware Ubuntu 22.04 guest

Tags: ubuntu, terraform, vmware, packer, cloud-init

I would like to create VMs with varying CPU, RAM and network configuration from the same Ubuntu template in ESXi.

When `$ packer build -var-file=packer/variables.pkr.hcl -var-file=packer/secret.pkrvars.hcl packer/template.pkr.hcl` is run, it reads the following `packer/template.pkr.hcl`:

```
variable "vm_name" {
  type = string
  default = "Ubuntu_Server_22.04_LTS"
}

variable "esxi_password" {
  type =  string
  default = "password"
  sensitive = true
}

variable "vm_password" {
  type =  string
  default = "password"
  sensitive = true
}

source "vmware-iso" "ubuntu-2204" {
  vm_name = "${var.vm_name}"
  guest_os_type = "ubuntu-64"

  iso_checksum = "sha256:84aeaf7823c8c61baa0ae862d0a06b03409394800000b3235854a6b38eb4856f"
  iso_url = "https://REDACTED/ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64.iso"

  http_directory = "/home/REDACTED/packer/http"

  shutdown_command = "sudo shutdown -P now"

  remote_type = "esx5"

  remote_datastore = "REDACTED"
  remote_host = "REDACTED"
  remote_username = "REDACTED"
  remote_password = "${var.esxi_password}"
  remote_private_key_file = ""

  cpus = 8
  memory = 16384
  disk_size = 16384

  network_adapter_type = "vmxnet3"
  network_name = "REDACTED"

  headless = false
  vnc_over_websocket = true
  insecure_connection = true

  tools_upload_flavor = "linux"

  skip_export = true
  keep_registered = true

  ssh_username = "REDACTED"
  ssh_password = "${var.vm_password}"
  ssh_timeout = "15m"
  ssh_handshake_attempts = "100"

  boot_wait = "3s"
  boot_command = [
    "<esc><esc><esc><esc>e<wait>",
    "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
    "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
    "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
    "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
    "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
    "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
    "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
    "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
    "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
    "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
    "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
    "<del><del><del>",
    "linux /casper/vmlinuz --- autoinstall ds=\"nocloud-net;seedfrom=http://[{{.HTTPIP}}]:{{.HTTPPort}}/\"<enter><wait>",
    "initrd /casper/initrd<enter><wait>",
    "boot<enter>",
    "<enter><f10><wait>"
  ]
}

build {
  sources = ["sources.vmware-iso.ubuntu-2204"]
  provisioner "shell" {
    inline = [
      "ls /"
    ]
  }
}
```

`packer/http/user-data` contains the following:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  early-commands:
    # Stop SSH to prevent Packer from connecting too early
    - systemctl stop ssh
  apt:
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
    - arches: [amd64, i386]
      uri: https://REDACTED
    - arches: [default]
      uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
  locale: en_US
  keyboard:
    layout: en
    variant: us
  network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
      ens160:
        dhcp4: true
        dhcp-identifier: mac
        dhcp6: true
  storage:
    layout:
      name: direct
    config:
      - type: disk
        id: disk0
        match:
          size: largest
      - type: partition
        id: boot-partition
        device: disk0
        size: 500M
      - type: partition
        id: root-partition
        device: disk0
        size: -1
  ssh:
    install-server: true
    allow-pw: true
    authorized-keys:
      - ssh-ed25519 REDACTED
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu
    username: REDACTED
    password: REDACTED
  packages:
    - open-vm-tools
    - python3
  late-commands:
    - echo 'REDACTED ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' > /target/etc/sudoers.d/REDACTED
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/REDACTED
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- apt-get update
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- apt-get upgrade --yes
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- sudo cloud-init clean
```

This creates an Ubuntu 22.04 Server template which I can then use Terraform to provision virtual machines from.

`# cat /var/log/installer/autoinstall-user-data` run on the VM shows that Packer has successfully provided user-data. It has been executed, proven by my ability to login via SSH.

When `$ terraform apply -var-file=secret.tfvars` is run within my terraform directory, it reads the following `main.tf` with `provider "esxi"` provided by https://github.com/josenk/terraform-provider-esxi:

```
variable "vm_name" {
  description = "The name of the virtual machine"
  default     = "ubuntu-terraformed"
  type        = string
}

variable "esxi_password" {
  description = "The password for the ESXi root user"
  type        = string
}

provider "esxi" {
  esxi_hostname = "REDACTED"
  esxi_username = "REDACTED"
  esxi_password = "${var.esxi_password}"
}

data "template_file" "Test" {
  template = file("userdata.tpl")
  vars = {
    HOSTNAME = "${var.vm_name}"
  }
}

resource "esxi_guest" "Test" {
  guest_name = "${var.vm_name}"
  disk_store = "REDACTED"

  clone_from_vm = "Ubuntu_Server_22.04_LTS"

  network_interfaces {
    virtual_network = "REDACTED"
    nic_type = "vmxnet3"
  }

  network_interfaces {
    virtual_network = "REDACTED"
    nic_type = "vmxnet3"
  }

  network_interfaces {
    virtual_network = "REDACTED"
    nic_type = "vmxnet3"
  }

  network_interfaces {
    virtual_network = "REDACTED"
    nic_type = "vmxnet3"
  }

  network_interfaces {
    virtual_network = "REDACTED"
    nic_type = "vmxnet3"
  }

  network_interfaces {
    virtual_network = "REDACTED"
    nic_type = "vmxnet3"
  }

  network_interfaces {
    virtual_network = "REDACTED"
    nic_type = "vmxnet3"
  }

  guestinfo = {
    "userdata.encoding" = "gzip+base64"
    "userdata"          = base64gzip(data.template_file.Test.rendered)
  }
}
```

`userdata.tpl` contains the following:

```
#cloud-config

hostname: ${HOSTNAME}
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp6: true
    ens161:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp6: true
    ens192:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp6: true
    ens193:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp6: true
    ens224:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp6: true
    ens225:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp6: true
    ens256:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp6: true
package_upgrade: true
#ntp:
#  enabled: true
#  servers:
#    - REDACTED
#timezone: REDACTED
#late-commands:
#  - curtin in-target --target=/target -- sudo sed -i 's/#NTP=/NTP=REDACTED/g' /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf
#  - curtin in-target --target=/target -- sudo timedatectl set-ntp true
#  - curtin in-target --target=/target -- sudo timedatectl set-timezone REDACTED
#  - curtin in-target --target=/target -- sudo systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd.service
```

This creates a VM based on the packer template with the correct guest parameters. The VMware guest configuration contains the userdata property which I have verified matches the supplied user-data after base64 decoding and ungzipping the guest parameter.

The issue I experience is that the VM does not seem to contain or execute the "second" Terraform cloud-init userdata.

/var/lib/cloud/instance/user-data.txt shows none of the second configuration:

```
#cloud-config
growpart:
  mode: 'off'
locale: en_US.UTF-8
preserve_hostname: true
resize_rootfs: false
ssh_pwauth: true
users:
- gecos: me
  groups: !!set
    adm: null
    cdrom: null
    dip: null
    lxd: null
    plugdev: null
    sudo: null
  lock_passwd: false
  name: me
  passwd: REDACTED
  shell: /bin/bash
  ssh_authorized_keys:
  - ssh-ed25519 REDACTED
    me
```

/var/log/cloud-init-output.log shows:

```
schema.py[WARNING]: Invalid cloud-config provided:
users.0: {'gecos': 'me', 'groups': {'sudo', 'lxd', 'cdrom', 'adm', 'plugdev', 'dip'}, 'lock_passwd': False, 'name': 'me', 'passwd': 'REDACTED', 'shell': '/bin/bash', 'ssh_authorized_keys': ['ssh-ed25519 REDACTED me']} is not valid under any of the given schemas
```

Is attempting to apply user-data twice, when my workflow is Packer generating a template, and Terraform applying a new VM with that template, correct? If so, where am I best to find out why Ubuntu does not contain and execute the second iteration?

As an aside, if there are any other recommendations I should consider please feel free to comment. I imagine I should be able to achieve this with the upcoming plan to implement Ansible, but I still need to set options such as Hostname.

Comment: The `cloud-init` for both Packer and Terraform should execute correctly. You would probably want to check the logs on the system after infra provisioning to troubleshoot the second `cloud-init`.

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard, I thought so initially as well. I've added some additional logs that I believe may be related while I continue to investigate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by changing the Packer build to the following:

```
build {
  sources = ["sources.vmware-iso.ubuntu-2204"]
  provisioner "shell" {
    inline = [
      "sudo rm -f /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-installer.cfg",
      "sudo rm -f /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/subiquity-disable-cloudinit-networking.cfg",
      "echo 'disable_vmware_customization: false' | sudo tee -a /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg",
      "sudo sed -i 's|nocloud-net;seedfrom=http://.*/|vmware|' /etc/default/grub",
      "sudo update-grub",
      "sudo cloud-init clean"
    ]
  }
}
```

The cloud.cfg adjustments are referenced in the following articles, and allow OS network configuration via cloud-init which was the final step in getting this all to work:

- [VMware: How to make guest OS customization with cloud-init engine work on Ubuntu 20.04.x and later](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80934)
- [VMware: Enabling or disabling Linux guest customization with cloud-init](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/59557)

Adjusting the GRUB boot command, as well as appending `cloud-init clean`, to the Packer build provisioning step ensures that just before final shutdown of the Packer-built guest, the VM will no longer attempt to boot from the initial preseed, and instead will use the VM guestinfo specified on next boot.

I also split the Terraform user-data out into meta-data for the instance identification and network configuration, leaving the now-uncommented NTP and timezone configuration in user-data.

metadata.tpl:

```
#cloud-config

instance-id: ${HOSTNAME}
local-hostname: ${HOSTNAME}
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    nics:
      match:
        name: ens*
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
```

userdata.tpl:

```
#cloud-config

package_upgrade: true
ntp:
  enabled: true
  servers:
    - REDACTED
timezone: REDACTED
```

*As an aside, a simpler way to configure network interfaces was to use the match directive instead of explicitly specifying interfaces.*

All items are now configured as intended. It is possible this configuration is only required in ESXi using `vmware-iso`, as I have not seen these steps required elsewhere.

The gecos warning appears to have been a red herring and I've made no further attempts to resolve that.